# Highcharts add&remove data to series in stacked-column chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am trying to edit stacked-column chart by adding/removing data and categories from highcharts stacked/column chart. But there are inconsistencies on chart as category names/value/count.

My add function /param:data/:

```
    //setting category names
    var categories = this.obj.xAxis[0].categories;
    categories.push(data.name);
    this.obj.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
    //adding new points getting the series by name
    this.obj.get("a").addPoint(data);
    this.obj.redraw();
```

My remove function/param:name/:

```
    var self = this;
    var cat;
    var data_series = [];
    $.each(self.obj.series, function(sKey, sVal){
        var j = sVal.data.length - 1;
        var isRemoved = false;
        var dt;
        while(!isRemoved && j >= 0) {
            var dVal = sVal.data[j];
            if (dVal.category === name) {
                dVal.remove();
                isRemoved = true;
            }
            j--;
        }
    });

    var categories = self.obj.xAxis[0].categories;
    categories.splice( $.inArray(name, categories), 1 );
    self.obj.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
    self.obj.redraw();
```

The result is like this: I can add new categories/points, stacks and columns properly. I can remove the latest categories properly, it shifts to left and they are rendered fine. But when I remove category A from the categories [A,B,C,D] the result is rendered as [C,D,3]. However, it should be [B,C,D]. And whenever I add any new category after this it increases the last number instead of the string I give.

I am wondering what would be wrong the code above and what the proper way to add/remove categories,points,data to/from stacked column chart is.

Here you can try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/gencay/UP55k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that values are incremented for x-axis, but never decremented. For example, when add point -> index for last point is incremented. But whenever point is removed (not only the last one!) that index is not decremented.

In general you have to play a little with `series.xIncrement` or (best) add fot each point `x` property.

jsFiddle with series.xIncrement: http://jsfiddle.net/UP55k/23/ (works only when check/uncheck the same value - shows only general idea)

Comment: Now I try to modify all `x` properties of points after deletion(your 2nd suggestion). http://jsfiddle.net/gencay/UP55k/38/ as you are going to see the `x` property seems to be set properly for each `series.data` but there is still inconvenience between chart and the object values(`x`, `xIncrement`, `categories`). :/

Comment: I mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UP55k/39/ 
Now after point is removed update each point using `point.update({x: value})` to set proper category.